# Subtract element width from body width, and add as margin to element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an image inside a container. The image should always be at full browser width (100vw). As my layout is responsive, and the container has a fixed width at a certain point (45em), I can't simply use negative margins. So I got an idea, but as a novice I can't seem to achieve it...

This is what I want to do:

- Check the body width
- Check the container width
- Subtract the element width from the body width
- Divide this number in two
- Add this number as a negative margin to an element

This is what I got so far...

```
var bodyWidth = $('body').width(); //Check the body width
var elemWidth = $('#content').width(); //Check the container width
var margin = bodyWidth-elemWidth; //Subtract the element width from the body width
```

I still need to divide the number in two, and add this number as a negative margin to an element.

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried:  
    $("#yourElement").css("margin-left:" + margin/2 + "; margin-right:" + margin/2);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track.

```
var bodyWidth = $('body').width(); //Check the body width
var elemWidth = $('#content').width(); //Check the container width
var margin = bodyWidth-elemWidth; //Subtract the element width from the body width
var dividedMargin = margin / 2; // Divide the margin by 2
var negativeMargin = dividedMargin * -1; // set number to negative number
$(element).css("margin", negativeMargin); // replace element by the element name you want to apply this to.
```

You can also replace `margin` by `margin-left`, `margin-right`,`margin-top` or `margin-bottom`.

Comment: You're welcome! Keep in mind that you can keep this in one line too, so you don't necessarily need 5 variables. My answer does make it more readable than keeping it in one line.